# Using SoapUI to test Login function of REST application

Tags: rest, authentication, soapui

I don't make this very general question post lightly, but I've maxed out what I can figure out on my own.

I'm starting up the QA Test Automation at my new company (they don't automate anything currently) and they've elected to use SoapUI for this procedure.

The application they're developing is a REST application (I don't really have any idea what that means) so I'm trying to build a REST request and Test Suite to reach our internal test server (which gets me XML that I am not allowed to post here - but it does reach the server successfully!) and then try to do a Login/Logout test.

I'm asking for help with methodology, because I have no idea where to start. I;ve Googled and trolled their support forums and looked in every corner of YouTube. Everyone is doing something different enough that I can't relate or use it.

Does anybody out there use SoapUI and test functional login in a REST application? I can write HTML/CSS and I'm pretty Java savvy, so I can do technical stuff if I know what to look for and what to learn.

Feeling overwhelmed. This was not in my job description when I started.

Comment: You are in the right place...before I can help you a few questions. Which version of soapUI do you have and is it the Pro version? How are you accessing the rest service, do you have a WADL? To get you started..[check out soapUI's guide](http://www.soapui.org/REST-Testing/getting-started.html) and a good place to see the difference between soap and rest would be http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/tip/REST-vs-SOAP-How-to-choose-the-best-Web-service

Comment: oh..btw..You should bring a consultant who knows this stuff so that you can focus on other aspects of setting up test automation than doing actual testing...just my two cents :)

Comment: I have SoapUI 5.0.0; I have read almost all of the documentation SoapUI provides and am beginning to form a more complete picture. One of the elements I was missing - answered in the next post down by inf3rno - was that REST has to send new credentials with each request. Whoa. So I'm getting my login Token back at login and trying to figure out how to distribute that to each Request by using a Temporary Parameter and transferring it with a Transfer Step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should start with REST, and after that with SoapUI.

It is hard to catch the essence of *REST*.

It is like the **hybrid of *SOAP* and a *simple HTML driven web application***. By *SOAP* you describe your *web service* with a *WSDL*. By a *web application* you **send back *hypermedia***, so you don't have to write a *WSDL* or any descriptor to your application. This is ***convention over configuration***...

***REST* uses the same approach, so it sends back *hypermedia*** as well, but it sends **not *HTML***, because it is not machine processable. The hypermedia sent by a *REST API* is **usually an *XML* or a *JSON* derivative**, for example [*ATOM+XML*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28standard%29), [*JSON-LD*](http://json-ld.org/), etc... **If your *web service* does not send back *hyperlinks*, then it is not a real *REST* service** just a *SOAP* web service with some *REST* constraints. There is a big difference. By *SOAP* you have to know everything about the operation name and the parameters if you want to send a request. If something changes, then your *SOAP client* breaks immediately. **By *REST* your automated client follows *links*, checks** their ***link-relation***, or the bound ***linked data*** and recognizes which *link* is what it was looking for. So the modification of the *link*'s *url* is irrelevant in the *client*, because it **follows the *vocabulary*** of the application, for example: [*hydra*](http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/) is a project which tries to describe these application level semantics in a general way, and tries to bind it to *open linked data*.

So **at first you have to check that you have a real *REST API***, which follows the *[HATEOAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS)* principle, or just a *REST* like *SOAP* *web service*. This is very important if you want to write [*end to end tests*](http://www.techopedia.com/definition/7035/end-to-end-test) against it. **By testing *REST*, you have to follow the *links* in your tests returned by the *web API*. By testing *REST* like *SOAP*, you have to build the *links* yourself in your tests...** How to build such a *link*? I am sure you got a description of your *REST API*, but a link looks usually something like this in a `JSON` format:

`{
    rel: "link-relations",
    method: "METHOD",
    href: "domain/api-root/version/resource-path?map-reduce",
    data: {...},
    title: "...",
    ...
}`

Ofc. there is some difference by every *hypermedia*, so **you have to check your *XML* hypermedia type, how it represents links**... The **`link-relations` and maybe other attributes bind your data to the *semantics*** of your *REST API*. The **`METHOD` is always a *verb***, usually: *GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE*, maybe *OPTIONS*, and so on... There are only a few [*REST verbs*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Applied_to_web_services), each of them **has a specific meaning**. **In the *url*:** The **`domain` is the domain name** of your application, e.g. `https://example.com`. The **`api-root` is the root of your `REST API`**, usually `/api`. The **`version` is the version number of the currently used *API***, usually `/v1`. Only non backward compatible vocabulary changes should affect this version number. The **`resource-path` is the path of your *resource***, usually `/users` or `/users/inf3rno`, etc... By REST you have *resources*. Each of them has a **unique** `resource-path`, and as you can see, **every word in that path is a *noun***. So resources are **something you can modify or display with a *verb***. For example a `GET /users/inf3rno` should return a *representation* of my profile page, and a `PATCH /users/inf3rno {nick: "Leslie"}` will turn my nick name: `inf3rno` into `Leslie`. By *REST* every resource should have only a single *resource-path*, so this is always a *unique identifier*, therefore the previous example with *PATCH* was not so perfect if you want to have multiple users with the same nick... The **`map-reduce` in the *queryString*** of the *url*, and it contains the ***sorting*, *pagination* and *filtering*** settings of the *resource* you want to modify or display. For example you can retrieve some data of every user with a first name: "Leslie" with `GET /users?filters="firstName: 'Leslie'"&page=3&count=25`. There is a difference between the following *url*-s: `/users?id="inf3rno"` and `/users/inf3rno`. The first one points to a *collection resource* and filters the result by its *representation*, the second one points to a single *item resource*. So a *GET* should return a *collection representation* with a single item by the first one, and an *item representation* by the seconds one. By the *resource* modifying *methods* there is no difference between the 2 urls... So it is recommended to add only a *unique identifier* to the `resource-path` if you want to select an *item resource* from a collection. By *reducing* the *collection representation* in any other ways, you have to add the *filters* to the *queryString*. The **`data` part contains the *params* from the *input fields***. The **`title` is the title of the *link***, and so on... You can use [*url-templates*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_Template) of you want to put *input params* to the *url* as well...
**By *REST* the *client* maintains the *session*, and it sends the *credentials* (username, password) with every request.** This is because the *REST service* is like John Snow, it does not know anything about the *session* or the *identity* of the *user*. **It has to *authenticate* every *request*.** To do that it uses a *`credentials -> permissions` cache*. This is a good approach, because the *service* scales very well if it does not have to maintain the *session*, which is part of the *application state* (the state of the client)... The *REST service* maintains only the *resource state*, which is not dependent on the *clients*...

**The *response* to your *REST requests* is usually a *hypermedia* which contains the *links* you can follow and the *data* you requested. By *REST* like *SOAP* *web services* you get only the data in a *JSON* or *XML* format. Every response should contain a proper status header.** The most frequent status codes are:

- 200 - ok (by successful *PUT, PATCH and GET*)
- 201 - created (by successful *POST*)
- 202 - accepted (by async request with eventual consistency)
- 204 - no content (by successful *DELETE*)
- 206 - partial content (by pagination with range headers)
- 301 - moved permanently (by migration)
- 304 - not modified (by cache)
- 400 - bad request (by invalid input)
- 401 - unauthorized (if no password given, or wrong username or password)
- 403 - access denied (if your account does not have permission to perform the task)
- 404 - not found (by unknown resource)
- 409 - conflict (by concurrency issues or duplicated request or db constraint problems)
- 410 - gone (if the resource was present before, but it is already deleted)
- 415 - unsupported media type (if the client wants the response in an unknown media type)
- 500 - internal server error (if the request was okay, but something went wrong by processing it)

**By any error you have to send a detailed error message with a custom error code, which is understandable for the users, not just the developers...**

That's how a *REST API* looks like.

**To test it with *e2e tests* you have to set *fixtures* send *REST requests* and check their *response*. So it is like any other test...** The *SoapUI* is not necessarily the best tool to do that, I read many complaints about it... I personally never used it, but it is not so hard to write your custom testing system. You need a testing framework, which can compare expected and actual values. You need something to send *HTTP requests*, or simply *mock out* the *HTTP framework* of the *REST API*. You need something for the *fixture*. By *integration tests* you can *mock out* the *business logic* and the *HTTP framework* as well, so by those you just *inject* the *mock* *dependencies* and check the calls. By *e2e tests* you need a test data set, and compare it with the result *XML* in your case... If you want to *e2e test* your client, you can use *selenium* if it is *HTML* based, maybe with [nightwatch.js](http://nightwatchjs.org/). By testing a real *REST API*, you'll need an *automated browser*, like *selenium* for your *REST API* implementation, which can select and follow the proper *links*. If you are developing the *REST API* you would write a browser like that anyways if you want an example *client* for your 3rd party client developers.

Comment: This is incredible. I clearly have a great deal of homework to do. I'm incredibly grateful for all this information. I can confirm that our application is REST by virtue of the Chrome Network inspector. I have a steady supply of POST and GET methods. I can "log in" and retrieve my access token via XPATH. We're doing all our responses in JSON, so specifically in SoapUI my retrieval property is ResponseAsXML because it needs to convert it so I can derive an XPATH. Now I need to figure out how to keep my authentication going knowing that the server doesn't maintain any session information...

Comment: Yepp, I love REST too. :-) It's only real competition is websockets and a message queue like ZMQ, but if you don't want to write a real time application, then REST is more than enough.