# Can SOAPUI be used to create REST Test Cases before the Webservice is developed?

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, soapui, testcase

I'm a QA and know a little about coding, the developers will convert our SOAP webservice to REST and I want to write tests for this. Basically I want to read our SOAP XML, understand the request/parameters and create a REST Test Case in SOAPUI to be run when they finish the implementation.
Is it possible?

Sorry for my poor english, it's not my native language.

Comment: Anything is possible! First thing you should do is talk to your developers, and find out how the team intends to work through this project. I would expect there would be a certain amount of mocks developed, which can be used to start writing your tests against.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, it's possible.

However, if the developers will be aiming for [REST level 3](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html#level3), testing this through hard-coded URLs inside SOAPUP kinda defeats the purpose - ideally you'd be able to navigate between resources through discoverable links.

[HAL Browser](https://github.com/mikekelly/hal-browser) is one useful tool for navigating [such](https://api-sandbox.foxycart.com/hal-browser/browser.html#/) RESTful APIs, however you need a dedicated tool for testing.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23299847/1791065)'s an very detailed possible answer for your question.